# Adding a field to the user document on new user creation (Meteor)

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to add a field, score, to users on creation.

I put this code in the server hook:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
      user.score = 1;
      return user;
});
```

But when I try Meteor.user() in the console, I don't see the score object.

Comment: Are you using the `useraccounts:core` package?

Comment: I'm using accounts-password and accounts-ui

Comment: I have a solution I can post if you are open to using a schema package as an alternative to using the onCreateUser hook.  I have had issues in the past using this hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're following the right approach for inserting the extra key, using `onCreateUser` is correct.

However, by default Meteor doesn't publish all the keys in the user object. On the client you will only see `_id`, `emails`, and `profile`. If you want to see `score` on the client you can either stuff it into the profile instead of at the root of the user document (easiest):

```
user.profile.score = 1; // in onCreateUser
```

or include the score key in a user publication on the server:

```
Meteor.publish('me',function(){
  return Meteor.find({ _id: this._id },{ fields: { profile: 1, emails: 1, score: 1 }});
});
```

And subscribe to it on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('me');
```